# Unable to edit my Craft 3 Plugin

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

I've managed to create a simple plugin for craft and get it into my project. It shows up just fine but I can't make any edits. I've tried editing the original plugin files and updating via composer and that doesn't work, and I've tried to edit the plugin files directly in my craft project and that doesn't seem to work as well. I'm sure there is a simple answer but I'm pretty lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a "host" project for your plugin, and then use a repository path to point to your plugin as described here: [So You Wanna Make a Craft 3 Plugin?](https://nystudio107.com/blog/so-you-wanna-make-a-craft-3-plugin#getting-a-host-craft-3-install-setup)

Comment: Thanks for the response Andrew, this is the post I had set up my plugin with but opted to use Xampp instead of homestead. At the time I had read it I wasn't getting along with Homestead very well. Can I not use Xampp for this?

Comment: The local dev environment you use should not matter.

Comment: I figured as much. I'll have to dig into this a bit more and see if I can give more details. I'll check the logs.

Comment: I guess I actually had it working. The front description part isn't updating but I went and updated a file in the src and the file in my plugin folder updated as well.

Comment: Ah, that's because that information is kept in the `vendor/craftcms/plugins.php` file -- you can delete it and do a `composer update` to force it to update

Answer (score 1):

If anyone needs the help with Xampp here is a link that should help. I had abandoned trying with Homestead as I have a terrible time with the Global and have only been able to get per-project installation to work. So I followed the [craft documentation for plugins](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/plugin-guide.html#loading-your-plugin-into-a-craft-project) and then set my Xampp up for multiple virtual hosts, here is the best walk-through I've found for multiple virtual hosts with Xampp. As far as I can tell it's the same idea as what Andrew is doing with Homestead.

https://www.rechnerhaus.de/en/blog/multiple-virtual-hosts-with-windows-7-and-xampp